# Udev rule to launch a service

Tags: systemd, udev

I have 2 UCANDEVICE USB dongles connected on my Raspberry Pi.
When I connect the 2 devices, they are visible in `/dev` (`ttyACM0` and `ttyACM1`).

To identify clearly each dongle I have the following udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="CANDevices", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/can-device-namer.py /dev/%k", SYMLINK+="CAN-%c"
```

where `can-device-namer.py` is a script that connects to `ttACMx` and returns the serial number of the dongle.

This rule works very well and now I get my two UCANDEVICES renamed in `/dev`

```
CAN-N16014350
CAN-N1613434B
```

Now I would like to start automatically a service that start `slcand` to bring `CAN0` and `CAN1` up.

For that I've modified my udev rule as following:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="CANDevices", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/can-device-namer.py /dev/%k", SYMLINK+="CAN-%c", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="slcand@%k.service"
```

My `slcand@.service` looks like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Serial CAN daemon (can-utils)
BindsTo=dev-%i.device
After=dev-%i.device

[Service]
Type=forking
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
Environment=SLCAND_OPTS="-o -c -s6" SLCAND_DEV=can0
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/slcand
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/slcand
ExecStart=/usr/bin/slcand $SLCAND_OPTS %I $SLCAND_DEV
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c '/bin/sleep 3; /sbin/ip link set $SLCAND_DEV up'
```

My probleme here is that the `slcand@.service` start on `ttyACM0` and I would like to use the name given using SIMLINK rule (ex `/dev/CAN-N16014350`) to ensure that `/dev/CAN-N16014350` is always started with `CAN0` and `/dev/CAN-N1613434B` with `CAN1`.

My final goal is to start automatically `CAN0` when the UCANDEVICE with SN N16014350 is connected and `CAN1` when the UCANDEVICE with SN N1613434B is connected.

Currently I have only 2 dongles but it shall also work with 3 or 4.
Maybe I have to define a config file with the assignments between device names and CAN names.

Thanks for your help :)